# Hapi.js custom 404 error page

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, hapi.js

Very new to Hapi framework. I am trying to make custom error pages. How do you route a 404.html page to 404 response?

would like the handler to be like so

```
handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply.file('./static/website/javascript/main.js');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use something like this:

```
server.route({
    method: '*',
    path: '/{p*}', // catch-all path
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.file('./path/to/404.html').code(404);
    }
});
```

By using the `.code()` method, you can override the default (200 OK) status code.

Comment: Thanks will check it out. .js was a typo. What does the * indicate?

Comment: It means this route will match all HTTP methods (GET,POST etc)

Answer (score 3):

A small update: since 9.x version you need to include [Inert](https://github.com/hapijs/inert) plugin to use `reply.file`. See this issue: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2729

(By this time documentation is not updated yet)

Answer (score 0):

Version 17 of Hapi and above has a quite different API now.

```
server.route({
    method: '*',
    path: '/{p*}', // catch-all path
    handler: function (request, h) {
        return h.response('404 Error! Page Not Found!').code(404);
    }
});
```